# Prove by induction $\frac{7}{8}+7\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2+...+7\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n=1-\frac{1}{8^n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> $\frac{7}{8}+7\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2+...+7\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n=1-\frac{1}{8^n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$

I first set $n=k$:

$\frac{7}{8}+7\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2+...+7\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^k=1-\frac{1}{8^k}$

And then $n=k+1$:

$1-\frac{1}{8^k}+7\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{k+1}=1-\frac{1}{8^{k+1}}$

And then I tried some Algebra on it:

$1-\frac{1}{8^k}+\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^k=1-\frac{1}{8^{k+1}}$

But not really sure what to do from here.  Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First comment: you should begin by proving the base case, i.e. for $n=1$.

That being said, for the inductive step:
$$
1-\frac{1}{8^k}+7\frac{1}{8^{k+1}}
=
1-\frac{1}{8^k}+\frac{7}{8}\frac{1}{8^{k}}
=
1-\frac{8}{8}\frac{1}{8^k}+\frac{7}{8}\frac{1}{8^{k}}=
1-\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{8^k}
=1-\frac{1}{8^{k+1}}
$$
and you can conclude.

Comment: I actually did prove that on my paper work, I just didn't feel like typing it up haha.  Sorry about that!

Comment: So it looks like you just distributed the $k+1$ to the fractional pieces.  Can't believe I didn't notice that!

Comment: For reference (it was not the idea of this specific problem), you may be interested in the general formula for the sum of the $n$ first terms of a geometric sequence: if $a\neq 1$, $$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.$$ This should look quite similar to what you have for $a=\frac{7}{8}$...